# Delay microphone input for several seconds

Tags: linux, microphone, pulse-audio, audio-recording, sox

Using [sox](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rec), I am able to record 10 seconds of mono-channel audio input:

```
rec -c 1 "/data/wav/${EPOCHSECONDS}.wav" trim 0 10
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I want the recording to contain 5s of audio from *before* I run the command and 5s of audio from afterwards:

```
Timebar

-10s      -5s      0s      +5s      +10s
-----------------------------------------------> (t)
            ^       ^       ^
start of recording  |    end of recording
                    |
             run rec command
```

I think the best solution would be, to set up a loopback audio device that buffers 5 seconds of audio and then leverage this virtual device as input for the recording.

Is this possible? Or maybe there is a simpler solution?

It should run on a headless Banana Pi M2 Zero SBC: No GUI, not much computing power.

**EDIT:** I played around with [PulseAudio's module-loopback](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-loopback) module but was not able to make it work, so far.

**EDIT 2:** I fiddled around a bit more and it seems that Linux does not start to buffer the input, before one starts a program that listens on the audio source. Maybe the only way would be a small program that listens all the time on the sink and forwards the data with a five second delay to a virtual mic.